# should a class manage its instantiated objects?

Tags: c++, class, object

lets assume I have a number instance of a class vehicle instantiated. if  the vehicle object wants to query other existing vehicles for some reason ( for example finding the nearest vehicle), should the class manages the instantiated objects through static members and methods as in the code below?  is this a good design pattern? is this a common standard? is there any pitfall if i take this approach?

```
  #include <vector>
  #include<algorithm>

  struct Location {

   double x, y, z;

   Location(double xx, double yy, double zz) : x(xx), y(yy), z(zz) {}

  };

  class Vehicle {
   private:

       Location l;

   public:

       Vehicle (Location ll) : l(ll) {

            vv.push_back(this);

        }

        static std::vector<Vehicle*> vv;

       ~Vehicle() {
           std::vector<Vehicle*>::iterator it;

           // removing the Vehicle object from the list of existing vehicles

           for (it = vv.begin(); it != vv.end(); it++){

                if (*it == this) {

                   vv.erase(std::remove(vv.begin(), vv.end(), this), vv.end());

               }

           }

        }

       Vehicle& find_nearest_vehicle () {

           // code to iterate through list of existing vehicles and find the nearest vehicle 

       }


  };

  static std::vector<Vehicle*> vv;
```

Comment: And please remove all the excessive blank lines so we don't have to scroll as much.

Comment: This is an approach and sometimes it is the right approach. We need to see how you intend to use this. But... `vv.push_back(this);` can lead to pain. Both automatic and dynamic allocations may be added to `vv`. Who is responsible for cleaning this list and how do you plan to manage automatic allocations that go out of scope? Consider a factory that creates and adds and if you go that route, why not a manager class?

Comment: This forces the program to have only one master set of vehicles. That seems a bit restrictive. You could *also* have other external sets *in addition* to your internal static one but that seems duplicative to me. I would think this design would only suit very specific and likely obscure needs tbh.

Comment: It also couples the responsibility that the class is modelling together witht the responsibility to create objects and manage lifetimes. I think this violates the single responsibility principle, and e.g. limits reuse of the class in different contexts. It also puts knowledge about the number of objects into the class and not in the level it belongs to, similar to what a singleton does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it into any of the typical OO scenarios used as examples:

- Does an animal know about every other animal?
- Does a car know about every other car?
- Does a color know about every other color?

What you are asking is really opinion based, but I'm sure most people would say "no". You use some kind of manager class to control the instances.

In your case I'd have a Vehicle which knows it's location and a VehicleManager which knows about all the Vehicles. If you want to know what color a Vehicle is you ask the Vehicle. If you want to know where all the Red Vehicles are - you ask the VehicleManager.

Your solution has a combined Vehicle/VehicleManager which relies on a static collection of vehicles so you can only ever have one set. If you use two classes as I've described you can have multiple sets. e.g. Vehicles of different companies or trucks vs cars etc - sure there are other ways to do this as well, but your solution locks you in. Using 2 classes is much more flexible.

So to answer your last comment: `do you think it's ok or is it a terrible design?` - It is terrible design.

Comment: Isn’t a manager class a code smell?

Comment: ok, i guess the better question is should a class manages its objects itself or should this be responsibility of a external manager class? which one is more readable and cleaner code? another related question that comes to my mind is that, how can the class or the manager class makes sure the references its storing are not due to temporary objects to avoid overhead?

Comment: @manni66 the problem is more with the name than the concept. Name it well and keep its scope tight and you're fine. What is a linked list but a node manager?

Comment: @manni66 What if you call it a factory? Or move it to dependency injection? I would say that managing its instance creation is usually not the responsibility of a class.

Comment: @manni66 I don't think so - you may be able to come up with a better name, but in this case you need something to keep track of all the vehicles and to ask questions like "Which vehicle is closest to point x,y?"

Comment: @Arash That is exactly the same question. The related question: No, C++ can't do magic. It can't know that the object is temporary. That is your job. I'd say the existence of temporary vehicles may be a code smell...

Comment: thank you all for your input. so overall do you think it's ok or is it a terrible design?